# How to invoke JAXWS application with AXIS2 engine in WAS 8.5.5.2

Tags: java, web-services, websphere, jax-ws, apache-axis

I had a Jaxws application deloyed in websphere 8.5.5.2 in multiple machines. In of the machine, my application is perfectly working where the other not. When i try to investigate why, i have found a strange situation.

I one of the machine, my application JAXWS services are invoking by WAS Axis2 engine i.e..com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet, and non working is invoking by "com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet".

Could any one please let me know what is the configuration required to invoke my webservices using axis2 engine in websphere 8.5.5.2.

**Working Copy:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <soapenv:Fault>
     <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
     <faultstring>GeneralException</faultstring>
     <detail>
        <ns2:GeneralExceptionFaultDetail xmlns:ns2="http://a.b.com/"                                                   <message>Unable to perform operation on method 'login' of                                  webservice 'SysServices' due to the following reason: Caught exception.[00000000003]Details:Unable to obtain naming service (org.omg.CORBA.ORBPackage.InvalidName: NameService:org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out:host=10.96.6.1,port=2809  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E06  completed: No).</message>
           <wsName>SysServices</wsName>
           <wsMethodName>login</wsMethodName>
           <callStack>
              <traceInfo>a.b.com.server.impl.SysServicesImpl.login(SysServicesImpl.java:310)</traceInfo>
              <traceInfo>sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)</traceInfo>
              <traceInfo>sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)</traceInfo>
              <traceInfo>sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)</traceInfo>
              <traceInfo>java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)</traceInfo>
              <traceInfo>org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher.invokeTargetOperation(JavaDispatcher.java:120)</traceInfo>
              <traceInfo>org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.dispatcher.JavaBeanDispatcher.invoke(JavaBeanDispatcher.java:118)</traceInfo>
              <traceInfo>org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.EndpointController.invoke(EndpointController.java:111)</traceInfo>
              <traceInfo>org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.JAXWSMessageReceiver.receive(JAXWSMessageReceiver.java:161)</traceInfo>
              <traceInfo>org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:212)</traceInfo>
              <traceInfo>org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)</traceInfo>
              <traceInfo> **com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet** .doPost(WASAxis2Servlet.java:1583)</traceInfo>
              <traceInfo>javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)</traceInfo>
              <traceInfo>javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)</traceInfo>
              <traceInfo>com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)</traceInfo>
              <traceInfo>com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)</traceInfo>
              <traceInfo>com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)</traceInfo>
              <traceInfo>com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)</traceInfo>
              <traceInfo>com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1071)</traceInfo>
              <traceInfo>com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)</traceInfo>
           </callStack>
        </ns2:GeneralExceptionFaultDetail>
     </detail>
  </soapenv:Fault>
```

**Non working error:**

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <S:Body>
  <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
     <faultcode xmlns:ns5="http://a.b.com/">ns5:Server</faultcode>
     <faultstring>org.w3c.dom.DOMException: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: An attempt was made to insert a node where it is not permitted.</faultstring>
     <detail>
        <ns2:exception class="javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException" note="To disable this feature, set 
com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.disableCaptureStackTrace system property to false" xmlns:ns2="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/">
           <message>org.w3c.dom.DOMException: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: An attempt was made to insert a node where it is not permitted.</message>
           <ns2:stackTrace>
              <ns2:frame class="a.b.com.server.common.MyHandler" file="MyHandler.java" line="209" method="handleException"/>
              <ns2:frame class="a.b.com.server.common.MyHandler" file="MyHandler.java" line="104" method="handleMessage"/>
              <ns2:frame class="a.b.com.server.common.MyHandler" file="MyHandler.java" line="41" method="handleMessage"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.handler.HandlerProcessor" file="HandlerProcessor.java" line="336" method="callHandleMessageReverse"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.handler.HandlerProcessor" file="HandlerProcessor.java" line="207" method="callHandlersResponse"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.handler.ServerSOAPHandlerTube" file="ServerSOAPHandlerTube.java" line="161" method="callHandlersOnResponse"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.handler.HandlerTube" file="HandlerTube.java" line="160" method="processResponse"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="639" method="__doRun"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="588" method="_doRun"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="573" method="doRun"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="470" method="runSync"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2" file="WSEndpointImpl.java" line="295" method="process"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit" file="HttpAdapter.java" line="515" method="handle"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter" file="HttpAdapter.java" line="285" method="handle"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter" file="ServletAdapter.java" line="143" method="handle"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate" file="WSServletDelegate.java" line="155" method="doGet"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate" file="WSServletDelegate.java" line="189" method="doPost"/>
              <ns2:frame class="**com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet**" file="WSServlet.java" line="76" method="doPost"/>
              <ns2:frame class="javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" file="HttpServlet.java" line="754" method="service"/>
              <ns2:frame class="javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" file="HttpServlet.java" line="847" method="service"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper" file="ServletWrapper.java" line="1230" method="service"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper" file="ServletWrapper.java" line="779" method="handleRequest"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper" file="ServletWrapper.java" line="478" method="handleRequest"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl" file="ServletWrapperImpl.java" line="178" method="handleRequest"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager" file="WebAppFilterManager.java" line="1071" method="invokeFilters"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper" file="CacheServletWrapper.java" line="87" method="handleRequest"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer" file="WebContainer.java" line="914" method="handleRequest"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer" file="WSWebContainer.java" line="1662" method="handleRequest"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink" file="WCChannelLink.java" line="200" method="ready"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink" file="HttpInboundLink.java" line="459" method="handleDiscrimination"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink" file="HttpInboundLink.java" line="526" method="handleNewRequest"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink" file="HttpInboundLink.java" line="312" method="processRequest"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink" file="HttpInboundLink.java" line="283" method="ready"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback" file="NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java" line="214" method="sendToDiscriminators"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback" file="NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java" line="113" method="complete"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener" file="AioReadCompletionListener.java" line="175" method="futureCompleted"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture" file="AbstractAsyncFuture.java" line="217" method="invokeCallback"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture" file="AsyncChannelFuture.java" line="161" method="fireCompletionActions"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture" file="AsyncFuture.java" line="138" method="completed"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler" file="ResultHandler.java" line="204" method="complete"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler" file="ResultHandler.java" line="775" method="runEventProcessingLoop"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2" file="ResultHandler.java" line="905" method="run"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker" file="ThreadPool.java" line="1864" method="run"/>
           </ns2:stackTrace>
        </ns2:exception>
     </detail>
  </S:Fault>
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Are you getting an exception? An error? An HTTP error code? What do you have in your server log?

Comment: Hi, yes , i am getting error like "<message>org.w3c.dom.DOMException: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: An attempt was made to insert a node where it is not permitted.</message>". I want to disable the JAXWS runtime and let the axis2 runtime will execute my application ... Application running under axis2 is working fine as expected ...

Comment: I need a approach where i can define/tell to WAS to start my application with AXIS2 engine instead of invoking by application using "com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet".

Comment: You want to use WebSphere internal Axis2 engine, or you want to use external engine packed with your application?

Comment: Hi Gas, I want to use internal Axis2 engine.Especially, my webservices should be handled by classes of org.apache.axis2 plugin. (JAXWSProxyHandler). Any changes in web.xml required. Any configuration changes required for the same in WAS 8.5.5.2.

Comment: The configuration of the transport servlet is in the web.xml of your webservice package. From the look of things, both services are returning with different kinds of SOAPFaults. How are you verifying that either one of them is working? If you want to change the transport servlet, just clone the config of the "working" webservice into the non-working one